# Can't create New Android Application in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am not sure why I cannot create a new application. I go to file > New > Android Application Project. After entering in everything correctly, neither the 'Next' nor the 'Finish' button light up and I am just stuck here for hours.

Comment: can u post screen shot uploading somewhere?

Comment: check adt bundle is upto date or not & Help->update software & also in windows->preferences check android sdk loded or not properly.

Comment: application name must start with capital letter.

Comment: do post the screenshot .. **all are waiting for that** :D

Comment: Screen shot please :)

Comment: Did you download the LATEST `ADT Bundle`?

Comment: What operating system are you running? If it's linux you could try running eclipse from the CLI to get some more info on what's happening during the hang.

Comment: Well I guess best time to switch to Android Studio then. Eclips won't be supported forever.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tGMP2.png @DIVA this is what i see. not sure if i did something worng.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tGMP2.png @maven this is what i see. did i do anything wrong?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tGMP2.png @AnkitDhadse this is what i see. did i do anything wrong?

Comment: i checked already. it says no update available. @pavanmvn

Answer (score 1):

Train yourself from developer.android.com

It provides you all necessary details for developing a Android Application:

[Create First App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

Create Project:

[Create a new project](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: @jingyi: You should go to Windows / Preferences / Android and where it says "SDK Location" add or remove the slash (/ ) at the end of the route and then put "Apply" , it reloads the Android environment and can create a new app smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Here you can follow the steps given http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-hello-world

Good luck,